# How do I find out which GCC toolchain is installed?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, gcc

I would like to debug my embedded target with *Insight* debugger.

The debugging host is Xubuntu 64bit, the debugging target is an ARM Cortex-M4 connected through a JTAG debugger.

According to [this website](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/01/31/debugging-embedded-linux-with-gdbserver-and-insight-gdb-gui/), I can compile Insight for my setup with these commands:

```
./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabi --disable-werror  --prefix=/usr
make
make install
```

Unfortunately, `make` quits with this error message: `/bin/bash: i686-linux-gnu-ar: command not found`, altough `ar` seems to be installed:

```
manuel@manuel-VirtualBox:~/insight/insight-6.8-1$ ar --version
GNU ar (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.24
Copyright 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) any later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.
```

---

### Questions:

1. How do I find out which toolchain string to provide with `configure` argument `--host`?
2. The programs I'm running on the target get compiled using the *[GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded)*. `gcc`, `ld` and so on are prefixed with `gcc-arm-none-eabi-`. Hence, do I have to change the `--target` argument to `gcc-arm-none-eabi`?
3. Because Insight is not installed by the package manager, I'm afraid it messes up the system and is not removable. Hence I would like to install it in my home directory. Is it enough to change `--prefix=/usr` to `--prefix=/home/manuel/usr/local`?

Comment: I suggest you use `/usr/local`, it’s sort-of made for this. On most distributions, it’s also in `$PATH` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I could figure it out by myself.

1. For me, it worked to just omit the `--host` argument. `configure` has chosen `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` by default.
2. Yes!
3. Yes, it seems so. Insight got installed in `home/manuel/usr/local` as desired.